# Using Continuation without Visualforce

Tags: rest, scheduled, continuation, job

I must check url statuses in scheduled job, but their amount is too big (exceeds limit, which is 100), so I tried to use Continuation object, but I'm not really sure if is it possible to use Continuation without Visualforce page? I want to check statuses on a weekly basis and store results in objects' fields. If there's another solution, please give me a hint, because I'm quite new to Salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running into limits on the number of callouts you can make in a scheduled job, the solution to execute a batch job and set the batch size to 100 (or some smaller number if you make more than one callout per record):

```
Database.executeBatch(new MyBatchUpdateClass(), 100);
```

The second parameter controls the batch size. A Continuation will not help you work with callout limits. You'll need to implement the [Database.Batchable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) in your class.

Comment: But isn't Database.executeBatch() for database modifications? I don't have a problem with limits here. I need to send http requests and 100 requests limit is not enough.

Comment: It doesn't have to be for database updates. You can batch across any type of processing that iterates over large numbers of records. Your issue *is* with a limit, the per-transaction callout limit.